# Running My First ASP classic code

Tags: asp-classic

I am learning ASP and I followed the steps given in W3Schools website to the T.
Whenever I try and run the first and only ASP file in inetpub/wwwroot/MyWeb Chrome says, it is not able to connect to localhost !

I dont know what extra details I have to provide, but please help me with this.

Comment: do you have iis running?

Comment: Information quality on W3Schools is not good enough more times than expected. If you want more information, please take a look on [www.w3fools.com]

Comment: Why are you even using ASP Classic?

Comment: Because, I have an application that is more than 20 years old, written in ASP classic that needs analysis done on it, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you check if iis is running?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is running.

Comment: Can you connect to just http://localhost/ , then try http://localhost/MyWeb/ and then http://localhost/MyWeb/yourfile.asp What do each of those returns. What version of IIS are you running? Have you got the ASP components installed?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already stated that IIS is running, the next thing to check is if a static page is working. Create a file called `Hello.htm` in the content folder for IIS (by default, this is `C:\Inetpub\Wwwroot`) that contains some simple, bare-bones code. Then request `http://localhost/hello.htm` from the Web browser that is installed on the IIS server.

After that, the next thing to check would be if ASP is enabled. Classic ASP is not enabled by default on IIS6+ ([Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737992%28v=WS.10%29.aspx))

1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, and then click Web Service Extensions.
2. In the details pane, click Active Server Pages, and then click Allow.

It may be a little different depending on the version of IIS you are running.

Where to go next will depend on what results you get from the above.